# Value assigned automatically to an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm doing a project where i have to implement an array of pointers to a structure ! The structure contains a word, its translation and a pointer to the next ! So, I have to create a linked list where the head's pointer is in one of the arrays' cells! I initialize the array in main with NULL values! After that i have to read a word from a file and then allocate a structure where i put the word read and its translation, which is in the file also. The file's structure looks like that :

```
hello;bonjour
```

There is a function called hash_string(word), which generates an index from 0 to array's size-1. So for the word hello, i get the index 2. I insert this word and its translation in the array using this function :

```
void remplissage_hachage (cellule_t **tabMajeur,FILE *fichier)
{
char  string1[20];
cellule_t *copy;
unsigned int indice;
int boolean = 0;
char *string2, *string3;
cellule_t *c;

while(fgets(string1,100,fichier) != NULL)
{

    string2 = strtok(string1,";");
    string3 = strtok(NULL,";"); 
    printf("string2: %s\n",string2);
    printf("string3: %s\n",string3);

    if(tabMajeur[2] != 0)
    {
        printf("Adresse 2 : %s\n",tabMajeur[2]->mot);

    }

    if(boolean != 1  && tabMajeur[2] == 0) 
    {    
        copy = tabMajeur[2];
        tabMajeur[2] = creationCellule(string2,string3);
        tabMajeur[2]->suivant = copy;    
    }
}
}
```

The insertion is done correctly, but when i read another word for example

```
bye;au revoir
```

the hash_string gives an index = 2 also and now i have to create the linked list by putting this value on the head of the linked list and putting hello as e second element. There is the problem because without making the insertion, array[2] gives the result = bye and not hello, so it  immediately overwrites the word hello. I don't understand how is all that possible ?

I'm also putting the structure and the main function to show you guys how i initialize the array :

```
typedef struct cell{

char *mot;
char *traduction;
struct cell *suivant;


}cellule_t;


int main()
{


    cellule_t **tabMajeur;
    tabMajeur = malloc(HASH_MAX * sizeof(cellule_t *));
    memset(tabMajeur,0 ,HASH_MAX);
    FILE * file = fopen("fichier.txt","r");
    remplissage_hachage(tabMajeur,"fichier.txt");

}
```

The file looks like this :

```
 hello;bonjour
 bye;au revoir
```

Thank you so much in advance ! I know the text is long but i wanted to explain everything to make it clear !

Comment: `fgets(string1,100,fichier)` does not match `char  string1[20];`.

Comment: Thank you for that ! I changed it, but i get the same thing !

Comment: Try to get out of the habit of declaring super tiny character buffers. You'll overflow 20 characters by accident. Use something like 1024 to give yourself some headroom. You also need a variable or `#define` to track the length of that as your `fgets` call presumes it has a capacity of 100 characters.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. That's the best way of getting a quick answer.

Comment: in _main_ `remplissage_hachage(tabMajeur,"fichier.txt");` must be `remplissage_hachage(tabMajeur,file);

Comment: In fact "fichier.txt" is the file's name.

Comment: @WillWost yes but `remplissage_hachage` gets a `FILE*`, not the name of the file

Comment: @WillWost you probably do not duplicate the strings in `creationCellule`, if I define that function doing the duplications all is ok, see my answer

Comment: `memset(tabMajeur,0 ,HASH_MAX);` is only setting part of the memory. It should be `memset(tabMajeur,0 ,HASH_MAX * sizeof (cellule_t *));`. (Technically, that is not guaranteed to set the pointers to `NULL`, but it works on pretty much any system you are likely to encounter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several problems in your code :

> ```
> char  string1[20];
> ...
> while(fgets(string1,100,fichier) != NULL)
> ```

*fgets* can write out of *string1* with an undefined hebavior, resize *string1* to 100 to have more place and in any case use *sizeof* :

> ```
> char  string1[100];
> ...
> while(fgets(string1, sizeof(string1),fichier) != NULL)
> ```

In *main*

> remplissage_hachage(tabMajeur,"fichier.txt");

must be

```
remplissage_hachage(tabMajeur,file);
```

because `remplissage_hachage` gets a `FILE*`, not the name of the file

If I do the previous corrections and I add the missing definitions

```
#define HASH_MAX 10

cellule_t * creationCellule(char * s1, char * s2)
{
  cellule_t * r = malloc(sizeof(cellule_t));

  r->mot = strdup(s1);
  r->traduction = strdup(s2);
  r->suivant = NULL;
  return r;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
c.c: In function ‘remplissage_hachage’:
c.c:33:12: warning: unused variable ‘c’ [-Wunused-variable]
 cellule_t *c;
            ^
c.c:30:14: warning: unused variable ‘indice’ [-Wunused-variable]
 unsigned int indice;
              ^~~~~~
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
string2: hello
string3: bonjour

string2: bye
string3: au revoir

Adresse 2 : hello
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

as expected

> the problem because without making the insertion, array[2] gives the result = bye and not hello, so it immediately overwrites the word hello. I don't understand how is all that possible

that means you do not duplicate the strings but do something like that :

> ```
> cellule_t * creationCellule(char * s1, char * s2)
> {
>   cellule_t * r = malloc(sizeof(cellule_t));
>
>   r->mot = s1;
>   r->traduction = s2;
>   r->suivant = NULL;
>   return r;
> }
> ```

so you always save pointers into *string1* in *tabMajeur*, so the second time the value you print use the new contents of *string1*

You must do

```
  r->mot = strdup(s1);
  r->traduction = strdup(s2);
```

or if you do not have *strdup*

```
  r->mot = malloc(strlen(s1) + 1);
  strcpy(r->mot, s1);
  r->traduction = malloc(strlen(s2) + 1);
  strcpy(r->traduction, s2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It really helped me ! This was my problem !